# What is the best practice for pass Enum type in WebApi

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api

we have a enum type as

```
public enum Country
        {
            UK = 1,
            US = 2,
            Japan = 4,
            China = 8,
            Germany = 16,
        }
```

we want to pass the enum in URL parameter, then webapi could search the result based on the country

Sometimes, we allow to combine the country as `Country.UK | Country.China | Country.Germany` ( so the number is 25 )

in this case, what is the best practice to pass the enum type ? should we pass number, e.g. country = 25 on the url ( not user friendly ) or pass the url something like  country=UK&country=China&country=Germany which the url will be very long and ugly....

Comment: Why not `country=25`?

Comment: Why does the URL need to be user friendly - will your users be typing their own URLs

Comment: @PaulF my user need use the web service

Comment: How does the user know what the valid enum names (ie country names) or values are? Are you just giving them a list of countries & matching numbers or are you providing an API with the enum? If you are providing an API why not adda method to generate the URL in your preferred format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Country.Us` when creating the URL which adds only the country name to the URL.

```
return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", "Controller", new { username = user.UserName, country = Country.Us });
```

This generates this URL:
http://somesite.com/Controller/SomeAction?username=username&country=US

which is good for SEO and user's point of view. Instead of `country=2` which doesn't mean anything.

And when getting the request:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SomeAction(string username, Country? country)
    {
```

If you want to pass multiple countries to an action, I suggest sending them by name still. However, I would change the name to `countries`

http://somesite.com/Controller/SomeAction?username=username&countries=US&countries=UK

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SomeAction(string username, Country[] country)
    {
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is about flag combination cases.

Comment: @Kapol I understood the question wrong. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Downvote removed :-)

Answer (score 1):

Enums will parse with "," not with "|".
Mark your enum with `Flags` and use "," in your URL.

```
[Flags]
public enum Country
{
    UK = 1,
    US = 2,
    Japan = 4,
    China = 8,
    Germany = 16,
}
```

URL: "Path to your ControllerMethode" + `?country=US,UK,Japan`